# How to upload multiple files on single statement in selenium?

Tags: file, selenium

I am not getting any warning or error message while executing the program.

```
wd.findElement(By.xpath("XPATH")).sendKeys("ABC.jpg","XYZ.jpg");
```

But no file is uploading.

```
wd.findElement(By.xpath("XPATH")).sendKeys("can we make CTRL+A operation" );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thank u guys, i got the solution from AutoIt,

ControlFocus("File Upload","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("File Upload","","Edit1",' Multiple image files path in Double quotes ') // ('    "abc.jpg" "xyz.jpg"        ')
ControlClick("File Upload","","Button1")

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be going about this while "file upload in Selenium" thing wrong, so that's what I'm going to address.

[This article by SauceLabs](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-file-upload) covers the basic steps to handle a file upload through Selenium in both Java and Ruby. Assuming you're using Java, there are a few steps you'd need:

- Set the `FileDetector` method for your `WebDriver`
- Get a `WebElement` pointing to a valid HTML `input` tag of type `file`
- Have Selenium type in the file's path *(Not sure if this requires absolute paths, but it's probably a good idea)*
- Submit the form

The following code listing demonstrates how to perform each of these steps:

```
wd.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
// point your webdriver to the page containing the upload form.
WebElement upload = wd.findElement(By.xpath("XPATH")); // TODO replace xpath!
upload.sendKeys("/path/to/ABC.jpg");
upload.submit(); // NOTE: Submits the form *containing* the upload field!
```

Because you've set the file detection method to `LocalFileDetection`, Selenium will be able to find the appropriate file. If this is not set, then Selenium defaults to the `UselessFileDetection` implementation, which fails every time to avoid accidental file uploads.

Caveat: If you're using a Javascript or Flash-based multiple file upload system, then this probably won't work, since those typically bypass the original input field or handle upload independently from the form's submission.

Comment: Thank u, 
 
but,How to pass two image file paths at a time?

Comment: Wait, is your `input` tag set with the `multiple` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting an error because [`sendKeys()` accepts an array of `CharSequence` objects](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.java#L65). and you are conforming to that method contract

> But no file is uploading

That is because the way your code is written now, will actually send the text: `ABC.jpgXYZ.jpg`.

Comment: This explains why she is not getting an error (and I learned something from it) but it doesn't actually answer the question.